# Is querying a database from a php script significantly time-expensive?

Tags: php, json, ajax

**TL;DR**: I could either query a variable from a database or query the same variable from a very small json file in the same path as my php script (which is called via AJAX upon user input on my webpage). My question is this: will querying from the database be significantly slower than using a JSON file, or vice versa? I'm just wary of sacrificing speed/efficiency.

---

**Full:** I'm calling a php script from ajax to load a set of images to a webpage depending on user input. Basically the page accepts user input from a few different dropdowns, and the corresponding images are subsequently displayed.

My final dropdown is composed of values which aren't terribly client-friendly. The selections refer to meteorological variables (`tmp2m` refers to 2-meter Temperatue, `10mwind_mslp` refers to 10 meter wind and mean surface-level pressure, etc.). I'd like to replace these labels with something more readable (`2-Meter Temp`, `10-meter Wind / MSLP`, etc.)

I could either query the strings from a database (which already exists and is populated - I would just need to add an additional field for the client-readable names), or simply hard-code the labels into a JSON file and place it in the same directory as my php script (either way I have to do roughly the same amount of work). **Will I notice a difference in speed/efficiency by querying the database instead of selecting data from the small JSON file?** The JSON file would remain relatively static, except for when we add a new item to appear in the dropdown in question (a change that would be made in the database)

Comment: If all you're doing would be to pull an extra column, i.e. you have to pull this data any way and you're just adding a returned column, then do that. Otherwise it's gonna depend largely on database load etc., but in general reading a static file would in theory be faster than calling ajax -> running commands through php to connect to your database-> returning those in values to PHP -> returning them to the output of the page. Realistically, do whatever is easiest.

Comment: @Jhecht Thanks for the tip. I'm only querying the database in an external Python file which is writing the images. I have yet to connect to the database via PHP for anything. So I'm really just wondering if there was going to be a time-intensive issue with connecting to the DB to do something I could just as easily hard-code into a JSON. Still have yet to make a decision, I guess

Comment: serving a static json will always be faster then doing a query on a database, but I think is over-optimization. Do what's best for usability and maintenance.

Comment: @PaunNarcisIulian cheers!